# How to get users in few specific groups in OKTA

Tags: java, single-sign-on, http-status-code-403, okta, http-status-code-405

I need to get the list of users in a specific group or I can filter the group in my code. I need the list of users in my application.

I tried the following nothing worked.

```
https://xxx.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/
https://xxx.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users//groups
https://xxx.oktapreview.com/api/v1/groups?filter=type eq admin_name
https://xxx.oktapreview.com/api/v1/groups?q=admin_name
https://xxx.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/groups
https://xxx.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/api/v1/groups
```

Can someone help me. I am getting 4xx error for all the above when i try in java

I have posted 2 different post for with the details.

[OKTA return 400 error while hitting /groups endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69997390/okta-return-400-error-while-hitting-groups-endpoint)

[OKTA return 405 error for while hitting /groups endpoint for the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982540/okta-return-405-error-for-while-hitting-groups-endpoint-for-the-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API call didn't work for me unfortunately got 405 error. Using okta sdk solved the issue. There is a built in listGroups method helped.

Answer (score 0):

Users in specific groups can be retrieved using the groupId and then used the id to list the users in each of them. For eg:

```
GET /api/v1/groups/${groupId}/users
```

More details related to this API is provided here: https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/How-to-use-Okta-APIs-to-list-users-in-a-group?language=en_US